# How to align List items at the bottom?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here is my view:

```
struct NewView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Spacer()
                Text("Hello")
                    .frame(alignment:.bottom)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I simply want the items of my `List` to show at the bottom of the container, not the top. How can I achieve this?

PS: The amount of list items is dynamic (could be 2, 3, 4, 5 6 etc)

Edit: This works but not when another list is added:

```
struct DemoFlippedList: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Text("Available slot")
                    .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))
                    
            }
            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))
            List {
                Text("Taken slot")
                    .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))
                    
            }
            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it OK to use ForEach instead of List?

Comment: Yes it is as long as I can keep the same style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your final goal, but here is possible approach.

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoFlippedList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Test")
                .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))
                
        }
        .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: -1.0))
    }
}
```